# Setting up POST request correctly

Tags: c++, json, post

I'm trying to set up a POST request as with Pythons requests package, but in C++.

It should be equivalent to

```
url = "https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/Api/GetBalance"
post = '{"Currency": "BTC"}'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Authorization': 'amx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:V/xxxxxxxxxxx/LuR2fRTWzxxxxxxxxxmeNkY=:111111111111'}
```

`rep = requests.post(url, data=post, header = headers)`

Then I'm trying to replicate this in C++ using [JSON library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/) and this [cURL wrapper](https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr). The [documentation](https://whoshuu.github.io/cpr/advanced-usage.html) is not that clear to me.

```
auto header = json;
header["Content-Type"]="application/json; charset=utf-8";
header["Authorization"]="amx xxxxxxxx:V/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx=:11111111";
auto pair = json;
pair["Curency"] = "BTC";        

response = cpr::Post(cpr::Url{"https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/Api/GetBalance"},
                                          cpr::Payload{pair},
                                      cpr::Header{header});
```

It throws plenty of errors. I manage to make it compile by putting it all together :

```
response = cpr::Post(cpr::Url{"https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/Api/GetBalance"},
                              cpr::Payload{{"Currency","BTC"}},
                              cpr::Header{{"Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"},{"Authorization", "amx xxxxxxxxx:V/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx=:1111111111"}});
```

and then it throws the following error: `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: parse error - unexpected '?' (<parse error>)
Abort trap: 6`

Any ideas, please?